# Can't use toolbin helper/prologue files with Ghostscript 10.xxx

Tags: ghostscript, restriction

I try to use helper files from ./gs/lib or ./gs/toolbin like pdf_info.ps or extractICCProfiles.ps. The result always contains this response:

```
Current allocation mode is local
Last OS error: Permission denied
```

Also when I add `-dNOSAVER -` in order to follow regulation for gs older than 9.5 I can't get it to work. Please see 2 samples below for details.

Sample 1:

```
gs -q -dNODISPLAY extractICCprofiles.ps -c "(ICC_) (test.pdf) extractICCprofiles quit"                            
Error: /invalidfileaccess in --file--
Operand stack:
   (test.pdf)   (r)
Execution stack:
   %interp_exit   .runexec2   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   2   %stopped_push   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   false   1   %stopped_push   .runexec2   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   2   %stopped_push   --nostringval--   --nostringval--
Dictionary stack:
   --dict:770/1123(ro)(G)--   --dict:0/20(G)--   --dict:81/200(L)--
Current allocation mode is local
Last OS error: Permission denied
```

Sample 2:

```
gs -q -dNOSAVER -dNODISPLAY extractICCprofiles.ps -c "(ICC_) (test.pdf) extractICCprofiles quit"
Error: /invalidfileaccess in --file--
Operand stack:
   (test.pdf)   (r)
Execution stack:
   %interp_exit   .runexec2   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   2   %stopped_push   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   false   1   %stopped_push   .runexec2   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   2   %stopped_push   --nostringval--   --nostringval--
Dictionary stack:
   --dict:771/1123(ro)(G)--   --dict:0/20(G)--   --dict:81/200(L)--
Current allocation mode is local
Last OS error: Permission denied
GPL Ghostscript 10.01.2: Unrecoverable error, exit code 1
```

Comment: The switch you need is -dNOSAFER, not -dNOSAVER, it is documented too https://ghostscript.readthedocs.io/en/gs10.0.0/Use.html

Comment: The "V" was a typographic mistake. -dNOSAFER still does not help:
`gs -q -dNOSAFER -dNOPAUSE -dBATCH -dNODISPLAY extractICCprofiles.ps -c "(ICC_) (test.pdf) extractICCprofiles quit"
Error: /undefined in oget
Operand stack:
   --dict:0/0(L)--   Root
... shortend ...
Current allocation mode is local
GPL Ghostscript 10.01.2: Unrecoverable error, exit code 1`

Comment: But that's a **completely** different error! Now you're getting an undefined in oget instead of an invalidfileaccess. So clearly it did help. None of the 'helper' files (those defined in lib) use oget, the only programs which do use oget reside in toolbin, which is really intended for internal developer use. Simply put, you can't use extractICCprofiles.ps any more. That program relies on the old PDF interpreter, written in PostScript, which has been removed in favour of a new interpreter written in C. The on example you give in lib, pdf_info.ps, is **known** to work, provided you set -dNOSAFER

Comment: The valuable info you give is: "extractICCprofiles.ps relies on the old PDF interpreter" that makes things more clear. Hence I can use the old interpreter if I want to - right?

Comment: And pdf_info.ps creates the same problem.
`gs -dNOSAFER -dNODISPLAY -sFile=test.pdf pdf_info.ps
GPL Ghostscript 10.01.2 (2023-06-21)
Error: /undefined in oget
... shorten ... Current allocation mode is local
Current file position is 20264
GPL Ghostscript 10.01.2: Unrecoverable error, exit code 1`

Comment: You're using an out of date version with security vulnerabilities. You **can** use the old interpreter with that version, you can't with any newer version, because it's been removed. pdf_info.ps is supposed to work with both the old and new interpreters, and does for me, I have no clue (since you haven't supplied a command line) how you're getting it to use oget.

Comment: It is the same issue with the latest Version: 
`gs -dNOSAFER -dNODISPLAY -sFile=test.pdf pdf_info.ps                                     
GPL Ghostscript 10.02.1 (2023-11-01)
Copyright (C) 2023 Artifex Software, Inc.  All rights reserved.
This software is supplied under the GNU AGPLv3 and comes with NO WARRANTY:
... shortend ...
Current allocation mode is local
Current file position is 20248
GPL Ghostscript 10.02.1: Unrecoverable error, exit code 1`

Comment: Well this is the wrong place to pursue a bug, You should open a bug report and attach the specimen file. The code works fine for me locally. I can't comment on the problem at least in part because you have not quoted the entire message.

Comment: This forum does not allow longer post for me ;-) Which Plattform you are testing on?

Comment: I tested Linux and Windows. As  I said, if you think you've found a bug, open a bug report. You can also edit your question to add more detail (maybe you don't have sufficient reputation for that, I'm not certain).

Comment: Yes I think so too. I am new at stack overflow

Comment: FWIW your problem with pdf_info.ps was fixed back in October https://git.ghostscript.com/?p=ghostpdl.git;a=commit;h=0aa00f6ffb4c00af9969b3f3a8adfe70195a0ceb and I've just pushed a commit removing the two useless programs from toolbin.

Comment: Dear Ken, thx for making this clear - i have got the right solution from you! How do I mark you answer as the correct one or upvote this?

Comment: You can't, because I haven't posted an answer :-) I don't do answers on Stack Overflow any more, if you feel an answer would be useful for others then feel free to post one yourself and accept it.